# how to change the kitchen order content in odoo POS

Tags: odoo, pos

I want to add some content to kitchen order, and I can't find the proper file to change from.

I'm using odoo 10 in Ubuntu server which I have access to by SSH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its just simple as it is the file link  is ( if you're using odoo10 community)

XML file path :

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/pos_restaurant/static/src/xml/multiprint.xml

JS file path :

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/pos_restaurant/static/src/js/multiprint.js

than go and change what ever you want to

remember sometimes you have to restart your odoo service to ensure that changes are in place